# Alias for column on table creation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a table to have a couple of columns with their aliases at the same time, I have been unable to do so, and couldn't find anything in the [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

**what I want**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[my_super_table] (
 [id] nvarchar(36)
 ,[data_1] "alias data 1" nvarchar(16)
)
```

**what I did**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[my_super_table] (
 [id] nvarchar(36)
 ,[data_1] nvarchar(16)
)
CREATE VIEW [v_my_super_table] 
AS
SELECT [id], [data_1] AS [alias data 1]
FROM [my_super_table]
```

Comment: *"[data_1] "alias data 1" nvarchar(16)"* Doesn't make sense. If `data_1`'s data type is an alias data type, then why do you then define a second data type afterwards? If would be `data_1 dbo.AliasDataType`

Comment: There's no such *syntax* nor functionality to create an alternative name for a column, but your solution using view is fine. Well, you could technically create a computed column that is a separate name, but i don't see the point to it. Unless you have an old database and you want to change column names without breaking it in million places. Could you explain the reasons you want to use alias?

Comment: the names that are wanted contain special characters and afaik its not convention to use in mssql, thats why @siggemannen

Comment: as long as you use quotes, it's not a problem. create table t ([手机告的世全所回广讲] int ) should work "fine". I personally avoid these kind of names because it's usually more complicated to type, plus the sql tools usually hate these kind of columns :D

Comment: I will suppose it wont be a problem in my case then, thank you

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, a view is what you should use here.

But perhaps you just want a computed column

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.my_super_table
  ADD [alias data 1] AS (data_1);
```

Comment: its a nice solution if I was to compute but not what I want, thank you though

Comment: So what *do* you want?

Comment: I already took @siggermannen's response, I will just use quotes and name the column as an alias without creating a view